# Ember children defined by a hasMany relationship suddenly change to embedded model

Tags: ember.js, local-storage, ember-data

I have the following model defined:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  message: DS.attr('string')
});
```

If I create a Post entry with a Comment, the JSON stored in my browsers local storage references the Comments as an array of IDs which works great:

```
...
"o3duh":{
    "id":"o3duh",
    "title":"How to write Ember",
    "comments":[
        "jf0a2"
    ]
}
...
```

However, the moment I add another Post, the JSON suddenly changes such that Comments are embedded:

```
...
"o3duh":{
    "id":"o3duh",
    "title":"How to write Ember",
    "comments":[
        {
            "message":"First!"
        }
    ]
},
"6kudl":{
    "id":"6kudl",
    "title":"Learning Ember is painful",
    "comments":[
    ]
}
...
```

Why is this happening? Can I prevent it? This is causing me problems because once it changes into this embedded format, the data cannot be read by the LSAdapter when reloading the page.

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/OnUXEti/17/edit) so you can see it happen for yourself and see the full JSON etc. To reproduce the problem, just create a post and add a comment then you can refresh the page without problem. Then add another post and try to refresh the page.

I'm not sure if the problem is with ember-data or the localstorage adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by modifying the LocalStorageAdapter so that it only attempts to persist JSON in the expected format.

You can see the pull request I submitted to the original author here: https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/pull/26

Hopefully it will either get folded into the LSAdapter project, or better still, someone will come up with a better solution ;)

Comment: This isn't the best solution, please see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the JSON issue by defining the inverse relationship on Comment:

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  message: DS.attr('string'),
  post: DS.belongsTo('post')
});
```

There are new issues now, but hopefully this will help.

Comment: "There are new issues now" is a bit of an understatement. When adding this inverse relationship (which I don't feel I need anyway) the Post model no longer contains a "comments" property at all. It doesn't "fix" the problem of writing an array of embedded objects, it creates a new problem of not storing the Comments array in the Post at all. No IDs or embedded models!

Comment: @mattburns I am not familiar with the inner workings of the LSA, but certainly it is possible to look up all the comments for a question, even if the way they are linked is only through a value on the comment. This is how many SQL STI ORMs work as it would be redundant to store a list of comment IDs in the questions table. I figured the problems were potentially with other parts of your app and that this might help you get on track. I spent a good while playing with your code and just posted in case it would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded snappy before, I'm very grateful for your time and comments :) I'm just frustrated that the simple blog example isn't simple. I'm coming to the conclusion that the problems I'm hitting are all within LSA and I shouldn't ditch ember just yet ;)

Comment: EmberData has gotten much better recently (with the big rewrite from 0.13 to beta), but I imagine the most effort and the most testing has gone into the REST and ActiveModel adapters (we use the latter in production). Good luck with the LSA!