# Extending TodoMVC to support multiple todo lists

Tags: ember.js, todomvc

I'm trying to get a feel for Ember by extending the standard Todo MVC. 
I want to introduce the concept of multiple todo lists (eg shopping list, reading list etc)

My code is online: http://jsbin.com/qidag/1/edit (I get slightly different/more verbose errors when not running inside jsbin)

In the browser, I create a couple of lists. Then when I try and visit a list I get an Ember error:

> *Error while loading route: Error: Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects
>   an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed object*

If I try and click the route again, the todos load like they are supposed to. 
Then if I try and click any other link to load a different list, I get an error:

> *Error while loading route: TypeError: undefined is not a function*

When I refresh on the route, the list loads without errors.

Can anyone enlighten me: why do I get different errors depending on how I visit the route? Have I missed some magic that ember does behind the scenes?

Secondly, my code doesn't work! 
The errors start appearing when I define my TodosController explicitly as an ArrayController rather that the controller ember generates. 
It feels like I'm missing a relationship - I've tried explicitly setting the itemController property and changing Route.map() (routes VS resources etc) but I can't get passed the "object being passed to ArrayProxy" error!

If someone could propose a solution or point me to the relevant docs, I'd be super grateful! 
Thanks
Scazz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Route `ListsListRoute` and template `lists/list`

I made [example](http://jsbin.com/joqidaza/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thanks @tropikan4 - much clearer.

I'm still struggling with your example code; the todos are not persisted between page reloads, but the lists are. I added some error checking on the promise returned by todo.save() but it seems to have been fulfilled. I tried the usual browser restart but can't see why the todos aren't persisted... any ideas? 

Thanks again!

Comment: I have been having this same issue so thank you both!

Comment: Fixed version: http://jsbin.com/joqidaza/6/edit?html,js
Note: no DS.belongsTo in Todo model.
There is problem in local_storage_adapter unfortunatelly.
Read this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132898/localstorage-data-adapter-and-hasmany-relationship-in-emberjs
and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878836/ember-children-defined-by-a-hasmany-relationship-suddenly-change-to-embedded-mod
Probably in latest version this problem was solved.

Comment: I didn't find any cdns with latest version so put local_storage_adapter.js directly in source. Seems that latest version  is ok. http://jsbin.com/joqidaza/13/edit?html,js